# utilizar la funcion trim() dentro de un array

Tags: php

sucede que tengo un select donde las opciones me las genera de una consulta a una base de datos. En ocasiones hay opciones repetidas pues al inicio o al final de cada opcion tiene espacios en blanco. tengo el siguiente codigo donde trato de aplicar la funcion trim() a un array pero me genera el siguiente error:** Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C** lo estaba intentado hacer de esta manera:

```html
if (isset($sistemas)) {
      trim($sistemas);
      $sistemas2 = array_unique($sistemas);
                            }
```

pero aun no se como poder aplicar el trim al array.

Comment: que valor tiene $sistemas cuando llega anexa un ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar array_map, que itera sobre cada objeto y puede recibir 2 argumentos, donde el primero es la función que deseas aplicar y el segundo es el arreglo que deseas operar

```
$lenguajes = array(  "     php", "     java", "  mysql");

$lenguajes_sin_espacios = array_map('trim', $lenguajes);

var_dump($lenguajes_sin_espacios);
```

Answer (score 5):

Con esto deberias poder dar solucion a tu problema:

```
$frutas= array('  manzana','plantano  ', ' , ',     '            cereza ');
print_r($frutas);//pintamos las frutas en un inicio

$trimmed_array=array_map('trim',$frutas);

print_r($trimmed_array);//pintamos las frutas sin espacios
```

Espero que te haya servido!

Comment: Estaba escribiendo lo mismo, jejeje :P  Acá esta la documentación al respecto: [PHP: array_map](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php).

Comment: me funciono perfectamente Miguel.

Comment: Perfecto! suerte!

Comment: Ojo, no funciona bien si es un array asociativo.

Answer (score 1):

Si se va a trabajar con un array multidimensional, el uso de `array_map` fallaría. Dejo aquí una posibilidad usando `array_walk_recursive` con el cual podemos:

> Aplicar una función de usuario recursivamente **a cada miembro** de un
>   array.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-walk-recursive.php)</sub>

Si tenemos el siguiente array:

```
$arrProductos = array(
                    array(
                            'id' => 1,
                            'Tipo' => "  Frutas  ",
                            'Nombres' => 
                                array('  manzana','plantano  ', ' , ',     '            cereza ')
                         ),
                    array(
                            'id' => 2,
                            'Tipo' => "Pescados",
                            'Nombres' => 
                                array('  Dorada','Atún  ', ' Merluza ',     
                                         'Salmón'=> array('   Ahumado', 'Normal   ')
                                     )
                        )
                    );
```

Podemos limpiar todos sus valores con la siguiente función:

```
array_walk_recursive($arrProductos,function(&$v){
    $v=trim($v); 
});
```

El resultado sería:

```
print_r($arrProductos);


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [Tipo] => Frutas
            [Nombres] => Array
                (
                    [0] => manzana
                    [1] => plantano
                    [2] => ,
                    [3] => cereza
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [Tipo] => Pescados
            [Nombres] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Dorada
                    [1] => Atún
                    [2] => Merluza
                    [Salmón] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Ahumado
                            [1] => Normal
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

---

#### Código de prueba:

**<kbd>[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/XZW8933)</kbd>**